# Parse error: Cannot modify user using php sdk

Tags: php, sdk, parse-server, back4app

I'm trying to modify user using following code.

```
$queryUsers = new ParseQuery("_User");
$queryUsers->equalTo("objectId", $userId);        
$resultsUsers = $queryUsers->find();  
$updateUsers = $queryUsers->first(); 
$updateUsers->set("status", $status);                        
$updateUsers->save();
```

But parse SDK returning following error.

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Parse\ParseException
>
> Message: Cannot modify user n7ZERX6Fls.
>
> Filename:
>   /var/www/html/mementuum_admin/application/third_party/parse-php-sdk-master/src/Parse/ParseClient.php

I have modified several other tables but not able to modify user table in parse.

Please Help.

Comment: Sometimes it's an issues with the sessions. You can try clearing the sessions associated with the user. It could also be something like the wrong masterkey but I suspect you wouldn't be able to pull data at all if that were the case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have clear the session of this user but not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.

Just we need to add '**true**' in **save** function.

Code should be following

```
$updateUsers->save(true);
```

Instead of

```
 $updateUsers->save();
```